# Why does python 'in' operator behaves differently according to tuple size?

Tags: python

In python2:

```
>>> 'a' in ('ab')
True
>>> 'a' in ('ab', 'c')
False
```

If I just want to test whether certain string exists in given tuple, looks like I cannot use 'in' operator when the tuple size is 1? Is there a consistent way to do this?

updated:

Thanks everyone. Tried this:

```
>>> tup='ab',
>>> type(tup)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> 'a' in tup
False
```

and it explains comma makes a tuple well.

Comment: And by the way, try `'a' in ('ab', 'c')[0]` or `['a' in i for i in ('ab', 'c')]`.

Comment: Since you are already doing this from the interactive interpreter, you could simply remove the `'a' in ` from both statements and see the generated output for yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `('ab')` is not actually a tuple but a string.

The `,` is really what defines a tuple, not the parentheses (except for the empty tuple `()` as @chepner pointed out).

Try the same operation on `('ab',)` and see what happens!

Comment: That's cool answer. Looks like parentheses are misleading cause "type(())" results in tuple type.

Comment: The empty tuple is the exception. `()` (no comma) defines an empty tuple; `(x,)` is a singleton, `(x,y)` is a 2-tuple, `(x,y,z)` is a 3-tuple, etc.